# Error building java chromium embedded framework

Tags: java, chromium-embedded, opensuse

I try to build jcef by instruction https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding
and I am stuck on setp `make -j4`

```
[ 71%] Built target libcef_dll_wrapper
Scanning dependencies of target jcef_helper
[ 72%] Building CXX object native/CMakeFiles/jcef_helper.dir/util_posix.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object native/CMakeFiles/jcef_helper.dir/jcef_helper.cpp.o
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable Release/jcef_helper
../../third_party/cef/cef_binary_87.1.12+g03f9336+chromium-87.0.4280.88_linux64/Release/libcef.so: undefined reference to `xkb_state_key_get_utf32'
../../third_party/cef/cef_binary_87.1.12+g03f9336+chromium-87.0.4280.88_linux64/Release/libcef.so: undefined reference to `xcb_send_fd'
../../third_party/cef/cef_binary_87.1.12+g03f9336+chromium-87.0.4280.88_linux64/Release/libcef.so: undefined reference to `g_settings_schema_has_key'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [native/Release/jcef_helper] Error 1
make[1]: *** [native/CMakeFiles/jcef_helper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i use oracle jdk1.8.0_261-amd64
and openSUSE 13.1